# How many permutations of $[n]$ are cycles of length $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles

Note that $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. A cycle of length $n$ permutation is when $1, f(1), f^2(1), \dots, f^n(1)$ range over all of $[n]$. How many permutations of $[n]$ are cycles of length $n$?

I was thinking of the circular permutation...

Answer (score 4):

You have $n-1$ options to choose the value of $f(1)$, it can't be $1$. Then you have $n-2$ options to choose $f^2(1)$, because it can't be $1$ and can't be $f(1)$. Then $n-3$ options to choose the value of $f^3(1)$. Continue this way and you will get the number of $n$-cycles is $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 3):

In cycle notation, ponder the ways to fill all slots, thinking of the cycles as vectors.  Clearly there are $n!$ of them.  However, any shift-and-wraparound of a vector is a different vector but *the same* cycle.  Since there are $n$ such shifts, the answer is $n!/n= (n-1)!$.